# How do I input a string after integers in a while loop?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to make a program that counts the number of steps someone made (the program should stop if the number is bigger or equal to 10000), but I can't seem to find a way to type "Going home" and then input the amount of steps that are necessary to get home.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalSteps = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            int steps = scan.nextInt();
            totalSteps = totalSteps + steps;
            if(totalSteps >= 10000) {
                System.out.println("Goal reached! Good job!");
                break;
            }
           else if(steps < 10000)
            {
                String home = scan.nextLine();
                if(home.equals("Going home"))
                {
                    int extraSteps = scan.nextInt();
                    totalSteps = totalSteps + steps + extraSteps;
                    System.out.println(10000 - totalSteps + " more to reach goal.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this: [Why is nextLine() returning an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040601/why-is-nextline-returning-an-empty-string)

This would work:

```
else if(steps < 10000) {
                scan.nextLine();
                String home;
                while (!(home = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                    if (home.equals("Going home")) {
                        int extraSteps = scan.nextInt();
                        totalSteps = totalSteps + steps + extraSteps;
                        System.out.println(10000 - totalSteps + " more to reach goal.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: when i use this, it gives an error after i input the extra steps, it doesn't do the calculation corectly and the first part of the program (the one with goal reached no longer happens) is not working

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with reading a newline. A simple (yet possible not the best) solution is as follows:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter("\n");
        int totalSteps = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            int steps = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            totalSteps = totalSteps + steps;
            if(totalSteps >= 10000) {
                System.out.println("Goal reached! Good job!");
                break;
            }
            else if(steps < 10000)
            {
                String home = scan.nextLine();
                if(home.equals("Going home"))
                {
                    int extraSteps = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                    totalSteps = totalSteps + steps + extraSteps;
                    System.out.println(10000 - totalSteps + " more to reach goal.");
                }
            }
        }
```

For more details on this problem, you could check out the discussion to a very similar problem here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/232053/nextline-after-nextint-or-nextdouble-gives-trouble

Answer (score 0):

if total score is 100,i will enter "hit" word in input then 10+ add on 100 and answer came in 110 and if i will enter "miss" word then 20-100 output came 80 but i enter 5 time "hit" or ""miss" after 5 times enter answer should be all hit and miss value and total in output how much hit and miss value entered

Comment: solve this equation using loops in phython

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34985738)