# Java Stdin and Stdout II why is it necessary to give scan.nextLine()

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner, nlp-question-answering

> **Problem Statement**
>
> In this challenge, you must read an integer, a double, and a String from stdin, then print the values according to the instructions in the Output Format section below. To make the problem a little easier, a portion of the code is provided for you in the editor.
>
> Note: We recommend completing Java Stdin and Stdout I before attempting this challenge.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> There are three lines of input:
>
> - The first line contains an integer.
> - The second line contains a double.
> - The third line contains a String.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> There are three lines of output:
>
> - On the first line, print String: followed by the unaltered String read from stdin.
> - On the second line, print Double: followed by the unaltered double read from stdin.
> - On the third line, print Int: followed by the unaltered integer read from stdin.
>
> To make the problem easier, a portion of the code is already provided in the editor.
>
> Note: If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() method, recall that nextInt() reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 42
> 3.1415
> Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> String: Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
> Double: 3.1415
> Int: 42
> ```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        //scan.nextLine();
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

In the above code if i comment scan.nextLine() I couldn't read the String input in the next line. Why is it necessary to give scan.nextLine() before the actual placeholder of String s?

This is the output I got.

```
String: 
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a newline character after pressing enter which is not consumed by nextInt() and it has to be consumed by scan.nextLine().

[Why is nextLine() returning an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040601/why-is-nextline-returning-an-empty-string)

Comment: Thank you for your solution.